# How to use regex to get different kind of values from string?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
19y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 148lbs
33y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 159lbs
21y.o. (Dec 3, 1998) 5'6" 143lbs
```

I am trying regex101 from last two hours I want the following information from the string.

```
{
  age: 19,
  dob: Jun 24, 1987,
  height: 5'7",
  weight: 148
}
{
  age: 33,
  dob: Jun 24, 1987,
  height: 5'7",
  weight: 159
}
{
  age: 21,
  dob: Dec 3, 1998,
  height: 5'6",
  weight: 143
}
```

I have tried `^\dy$(?:...)` but I am not able to come near by what I want. Really need some help  and explanation to how to get 4 different kind of info from a single string.

Comment: You could use 4 capture groups to get the values `^(\d+)[^()]*\(([^()]+)\)\s+(\d+'\d+")\s+(\d+)lbs$` https://regex101.com/r/4RNfwk/1

Comment: From a single example, there is no obviously useful generalization. Can you please [edit] to show several example inputs and the expected outputs, as well as one or two of your attempts so far? Also, update the tags to reveal which regex variant exactly to target; see also [the Stack Overflow `regex` tag info.](/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 4 capture groups to get the separate data

```
^(\d+)[^()]*\(([^()]+)\)\s+(\d+'\d+")\s+(\d+)lbs$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1** 1+ digits
- `[^()]*\(` Match 0+ times any char except `(` and `)` and match `(`
- `([^()]+)` Capture **group 2** 1+ times any char except `(` and `)`
- `\)\s+` Match `)` and 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+'\d+")\s+` Capture **group 3** 1+ digits `'` 1+ digits and `"` followed by  matching 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d+)lbs` Capture **group 4** 1+ digits followed by matching `lbs`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GP1IAt/1)

Or a bit more specific part for the date like format:

```
^(\d+)[^()]*\(([A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]),\s+\d{4})\)\s+(\d+'\d+")\s+(\d+)lbs$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0q3gp/1)

There is no language tagged, but for example in Javascript:

```js
const regex = /^(\d+)[^()]*\(([^()]+)\)\s+(\d+'\d+")\s+(\d+)lbs$/m;

[
  `19y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 148lbs`,
  `33y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 159lbs`,
  `21y.o. (Dec 3, 1998) 5'6" 143lbs`
].forEach(s => {
  const match = s.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    const result = {
      age: match[1],
      dob: match[2],
      height: match[3],
      weight: match[4]
    }
    console.log(result);
  }
})
```

Or with named capture groups:

```js
const regex = /^(?<age>\d+)[^()]*\((?<dob>[A-Z][a-z]{2}\s+(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]),\s+\d{4})\)\s+(?<height>\d+'\d+")\s+(?<weight>\d+)lbs$/m;

[
  `19y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 148lbs`,
  `33y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 159lbs`,
  `21y.o. (Dec 3, 1998) 5'6" 143lbs`
].forEach(s => {
  const match = s.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    console.log(match.groups);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this expression:

```
^(\d{2})[^\(]+\((.+)\) (\d'\d") (\d+lbs)$
```

The values of the match groups will be as follows:

```
0: 19y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" 148lbs
1: 19
2: Jun 24, 1987
3: 5'7"
4: 148lbs
```

One problem with this particular test string is that is contains both single and double quotes, which makes it tricky to define the string literal in most of the programming languages I'm familiar with. This is what it looks like in Python.

```
import re

test = r"19y.o. (Jun 24, 1987) 5'7" + r'" 148lbs'
expr = r"^(\d{2})[^\(]+\((.+)\) (\d'\d" + r'") (\d+lbs)$'
match = re.match(expr, test)
for g in match.groups():
    print(g)
```